# How to submit forms with javascript variables

Tags: javascript, database, variables, cookies, action

Lets say I have an HTML Form that submits to a database someones username, email, and phone number.

the form textbox variables are 
username
email
phoneNum

Now, when the form submits, it also puts this information into a browser cookie, which therein whenever they click specific links, I want it to call a javascript function that has the exact same action as the form and submits this information to the database again, without them actually filling out the form ever again,(unless of course they clear cookies).

So if they click a specific link 3 times after filling out the form, then the database should have 3 more instances of their information in the db, without them filling anything out.

Comment: OK, and what problems are you having with this?

Comment: Typically a cookie would just be used to store the user's id (either their email or an id generated when you first store their info server-side). Since that cookie gets sent whenever an additional request is made why do you want the additional submissions instead of just logging the cookie?

Comment: first you should accept some answers. Then why would you do this it, sounds very weird to store the same thing multiple times?

Comment: Does the links to be logged go to the same site as the data or to another external site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the above comments, and provided you have the cookies set for these variables and can read them, I recommend one of two methods for submitting the form.

1. Use a hidden `<iframe name='sendinfo'></iframe>` tag and a hidden `<form target='sendinfo' id='infoform'>` form. Populate the form with your info using JavaScript, and submit the form with `document.getElementById('infoform').submit();` on the click of that link.
2. Use AJAX to submit the form. I recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this; it's easiest. Use the $.post or $.get methods like this when the link is clicked (substituting your variables after the : in each):

   $.post("save.php", {username: username, email: email, phone: phoneNum});